# While loop question about printing i++ in java

Tags: java, while-loop

```
        int i=10;
        while(i<=10) {
            System.out.println(i++);
        }
```

why does this code outputs 10 once, what's the theory behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `i` is already equals to 10 when `System.out.println(i++)` is executed so the output will be 10. After that `i` becomes 11 because of `i++` however it will not be printed because the `while` statement will be false when `i` is 11.

If we changed the `i++` to `++i` in `System.out.println(++i)`, we will be get a different result. Variable `i` will be incremented first to become 11 and then `println` statement will take place; so the output will be 11.

Comment: So even if you print i++, i will be incremented 1

Comment: Yes. The way it works is that, it will print the current value of `i` which is 10 and then do the increment so that `i` becomes 11. After that it will return to the `while` statement to check if 11<=10 which is false and accordingly the `System.out.println` will not be executed again.

Comment: Yes, The purpose of the `++` operator **is** to increment the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the logic is simple. i++ is post-increment and it adds 1 in the value of the variable on which it is applied.
for example:

`int a = 10; System.out.println(a++); // it will print 10 System.out.println(a); // it will print 11`